# Cross-browser HTML5 video compatibility not working with multiple video formats

Tags: html, video, cross-browser

I have the different video files in the HTML `<video>` tag like so :

```
<video autoplay="" id="video" preload="auto" style="display: inline-block;">
        <source src="../register.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="../register.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="../register.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

But for some reason, in chrome it doesn't work. It only works if I get rid of the MP4 source, but then it doesn't work in IE... not sure what's going on here or the best way to approach this.

I have already gotten passed the step of creating video files for all browsers as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691494/chrome-wont-play-mp4-file) question, but it has not solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The order in which you list the sources matters.** In Chrome, once the `.MP4` video fails to load, the other sources don't even bother trying to load, so just by putting the `.MP4` source as the last source element it fixed everything.

```
<video autoplay="" id="video" preload="auto" style="display: inline-block;">
        <source src="../register.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="../register.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="../register.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```