# Video tag doesn't work in html5

Tags: html, video, tags

```
<video width=200 controls>
     <source src="../../../Content/111.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

it doesn't work. Path is correct. What is this??
Result is white window with play button.

Comment: the path probably isn't right. is that source available on that path from the page you're on, and using the same transport (http vs file) that you opened the page?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your problem using the browser's developer tools? Any error messages?

Comment: 404 status on file

Comment: how can i get file from C:\Users\Dan\PhpstormProjects\symfony3\src\YeepBundle\Content\111.mp4?

Comment: your path needs to be relative to the page you're displaying, and the web server needs to be able to navigate the relative pathing you're providing

Answer (score 0):

The html5 code below works for me in every browser except Chrome. Can you test in other browsers. Are you able to add another video in another format type? See this stack overflow question for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691494/chrome-wont-play-mp4-file).

```
<video width="200" controls>
 <source src="yyy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```